# How to save data changed in DXGrid to database

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, devexpress

I am new in WPF development, I use DevExpress data-grid (DXGrid).
I want to let my users insert, edit and delete records from database throw data-grid.
the steps I do :

1. I dragged a data-grid to my windows and set it's items source and columns.
2. The grid display data from database correctly but the user cannot insert new records, can't delete records, just can edit records.
3. I can't save changed data to database.

Can any one give me an example or tutorial that help me to do that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The user cannot insert new records, can't delete records, just can
>   edit records.

You should activate the [New Item Row](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6123) feature. By default it is hidden. To show it, set the [TableView.NewItemRowPosition](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridTableView_NewItemRowPositiontopic) to `NewItemRowPosition.Top`.

To delete a data row, use the [GridViewBase.DeleteRow](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpressXpfGridGridViewBase_DeleteRowtopic.aspx) method. 
Take a look at the [Deleting Rows](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6149) help-article for details.

> I can't save changed data to database.

The answers of this question can be different depending on data access technology you use. For example, when binding to DataTable, to post changes to the database, you should call the data adapter's Update method. Take a look at the following help article for details:
[Posting Data to a Connected Database](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6285)